# How to show some information while hover on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have few checkboxes. I want to show some information belong to those checkboxes while I hover on them. How do I do it using JS or JQuery?
Suppose this is my checkbox

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="monday" checked="checked">
```

I want to show a user "Hello User or the value 'monday' or some data from my Database. How?

Comment: Yes, this is possible (and jQuery **is** JavaScript). [What have *you* tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This question was a first hit in Google and helped me. Voting for reopen.

Comment: just wrap input inside span and add title attribute to span tag.

Answer (score 54):

Just add a "title" attribute to your HTML object.

```
<input title="Text to show" id="chk1" type="checkbox" value="monday" checked="checked" />
```

Or in JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("chk1").setAttribute("title", "text to show");
```

Or in jQuery

```
$('#chk1').attr('title', 'text to show');
```

Comment: simplicity at its best...

Comment: no good for touch screen

Comment: @SSED - there is no "hover" for touch screens. You'd need to use the "touchstart" event to try and create some facsimily of it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387341/884862  The HTML Title attribute and it's function was created before touch screens were a thing, so you have to rely solely on javascript to get what you want.

Comment: Hell of a code , woow :D

Answer (score 16):

You can use attribute title and on step rendering add value of title from your database

```
 input type='checkbox' title='tooltip 2'
```

You can use js plugin(you need to add value of requered text as attribute, see docs)
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Answer (score 12):

Here is your answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="monday" checked="checked">
  <div>informations</div>
```

and the css:

```
input+div{display:none;}
input:hover+div{display:inline;}
```

You have an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4M3j/)

Answer (score 3):

With an html structure like that:

```
<div class="checkboxContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 1
    <div class="infoCheckbox">
        <p>Info on checkbox 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 2
    <div class="infoCheckbox">
        <p>Info on checkbox 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"> Checkbox 3
    <div class="infoCheckbox">
        <p>Info on checkbox 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can easily show the text with "this" handler of jQuery which refers to the current element hovered:

```
$(".checkboxContainer").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find(".infoCheckbox:first").show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find(".infoCheckbox:first").hide();
    }
);
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdRX2/

Comment: This fiddle is not working !

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb" value="monday" checked="checked">

$("#cb").hover(
   function() {
      // show info
   },
   function() {
      // hide info
   }
);
```

Or you could just add title attribute to your element

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick crude stab (not tested or anything, and not fully understanding what you want.. let alone what you've actually tried.. maybe something to the extent of..

```
$('input:checkbox').mouseover(function()
{
   /*code to display whatever where ever*/
   //example
   alert($(this).val());
}).mouseout(function()
{
   /*code to hide or remove displayed whatever where ever*/
});
```

of course there are plenty of ways to go about doing the same thing, from maybe something using `toggle()` to something like `on()`